# Executable for the writer file with mkfifo halts

Tags: c, unix, mkfifo

In my understanding, according to the https://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo,

I got an implication that I must have reader and writer file, in order to

utilize the pipe file. The source below is the writer file,

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){

    int fd;
    char *myfifo = "./myfifo";

    mkfifo(myfifo, 0777);
    fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);    


    int PID = fork();   

    if(PID == 0){

        execl("./reader.o", "reader", (char*)NULL);

    }

    write(fd, "Rock and roll baby\0", sizeof("Rock and roll baby"));
    close(fd);
    unlink(myfifo);

    return 0;

}
```

and the source being provided below is for the reader file.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_BUF 1024

int main(){

    int fd;

    char* myfifo = "./myfifo";
    char buf[MAX_BUF];

    fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
    read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, MAX_BUF);

    close(fd);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    return 0;

}
```

When run the executable for the writer file, the command prompt goes into

halt, after printing a newline. My assumption for this problem is because the

open() in the writer file is not being able to detect the pipe file,

is that the case?

Thank you.

Comment: Unless you play tricks with arguments to `open()`, neither a reader nor a writer will return from the `open()` call until there is another process with the 'other end' of the FIFO open. That is, the reader waits until there is a writer, and the writer waits until there is a reader. You therefore need to fork and exec the child process before attempting to open the FIFO. This also solves another problem — you should have closed the write end of the FIFO before executing the child. The child would hang because it would have a write file descriptor and a read file descriptor for the FIFO; no EOF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you should create the FIFO before the fork, but only open the FIFO after the fork.  This avoids an assortment of problems.  For the most part, I've used `write()` to report errors to standard error; it isn't as convenient as using `fprintf(stderr, …)` though.

Note that the writer writes a null byte at the end of the message.  The reader gets the null byte, but overwrites it with a newline before writing the resulting character array (it is no longer a string; strings have a terminal null byte at the end) to standard output.  If the code used `<stdio.h>` to write the data (e.g. `printf("%s\n", buf)`), it wouldn't need to replace the null byte with a newline.

#### `writer.c`

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#ifndef READER
#define READER "./reader"
#endif

int main(void)
{
    char *myfifo = "./myfifo";

    if (mkfifo(myfifo, 0777) != 0)
    {
        write(STDERR_FILENO, "Failed to create FIFO\n",
                      sizeof("Failed to create FIFO\n") - 1);
    }

    int PID = fork();

    if (PID == 0)
    {
        execl(READER, "reader", (char *)NULL);
        write(STDERR_FILENO, "Failed to execute reader\n",
                      sizeof("Failed to execute reader\n") - 1);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (PID < 0)
    {
        write(STDERR_FILENO, "Failed to fork\n",
                      sizeof("Failed to fork\n") - 1);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        write(STDERR_FILENO, "Failed to open FIFO for writing\n",
                      sizeof("Failed to open FIFO for writing\n") - 1);
        unlink(myfifo);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    write(fd, "Rock and roll baby", sizeof("Rock and roll baby"));
    close(fd);
    unlink(myfifo);
    int corpse;
    int status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
        printf("Child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);

    return 0;
}
```

#### `reader.c`

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_BUF 1024

int main(void)
{
    char* myfifo = "./myfifo";
    int fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0)
        write(STDERR_FILENO, "Failed to open FIFO for reading\n",
                      sizeof("Failed to open FIFO for reading\n")-1);
    else
    {
        char buf[MAX_BUF];
        int nbytes = read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
        if (nbytes > 0)
        {
            buf[nbytes-1] = '\n';
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, nbytes);
        }
        close(fd);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Example output

```
Rock and roll baby
Child 43734 exited with status 0x0000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){

    int fd;
    char *myfifo = "./myfifo";

    int PID = fork();   

    if(PID == 0){

        execl("./reader.o", "reader", (char*)NULL);

    }

    mkfifo(myfifo, 0777);
    fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);    

    write(fd, "Rock and roll baby\0", sizeof("Rock and roll baby"));
    close(fd);
    unlink(myfifo);

    return 0;

}
```

After having the body of the code, where the execl is, moved above the

mkfifo(),

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_BUF 1024

int main(){

    sleep(3);

    int fd;

    char* myfifo = "./myfifo";
    char buf[MAX_BUF];

    fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
    read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, MAX_BUF);

    close(fd);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    return 0;

}
```

and having the reader have sleep() for 3 seconds, the programs started to

work; however, does anyone know if the two programs can open() the pipe file

exactly at the same time?

Thank you.

Comment: I think maybe you should explain why you have the extra null byte in the string written by the writer — it looks unnecessary to me (and you could use the same string twice, rather than using two slightly different strings).

Comment: To conserve time, I have decided not to stdout the exact size of the string in buf.

Comment: Well, instead of `write(fd, "Rock and roll baby\0", sizeof("Rock and roll baby"));`, you could use `write(fd, "Rock and roll baby", sizeof("Rock and roll baby"));`.  This includes the null byte in the data sent on the FIFO.  That has its merits; you either need to identify the length up front or use an end marker.

Comment: Forgive me on the misunderstanding of the first comment. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: NP — I see you mostly copied the code from the question on that point anyway.  I think you should be creating the FIFO before forking; otherwise, there's a risk the reader will try to open the still non-existent FIFO and fail, wreaking havoc on the best laid plans of mice and coders.  The open calls should both be after the fork, though; in the case of the reader, that's unavoidable, but not for the writer.